# Json Serialize Vector<Class> to json array (nlohmann/json.hpp)

Tags: c++, json

I have Class `RoomData` with this fields:

```cpp
#include <string>

class RoomData
{
public:
    int id;
    string name;
    int maxPlayers;
    int timePerQuestion;
    int isActive;
};
```

and i'm trying to turn vactor of RoomData `Vector<RoomData>` to json array
this what i tried:

```cpp
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

using nlohmann::json;

string serialize(vector<RoomData> roomData)
{
    json j(roomData);
    string jsonArray = j.dump();
    return jsonArray;
}
```

But it gives me these Errors:
`C2338 forcing MSVC stacktrace to show which T we're talking about.`
`C2338 could not find to_json() method in T's namespace`
`C2065 'force_msvc_stacktrace': undeclared identifier`
`C2825 'decayed': must be a class or namespace when followed by '::'`
`C2510 'decayed': left of '::' must be a class/struct/union`

Comment: Also, what library your class `json` is from?

Comment: i'm using in json.hpp @HolyBlackCat

Comment: "json.hpp" is not enough information. I could make a file called "json.hpp" right now, with any old contents. Which library are you using? What is it called, who wrote it, what version is it? Provide _detailed_ information.

Comment: @NoneName with the limited info you've provided my only guess is that your json lib doesn't know how to serialize your class. And how would it know (there is no reflection in C++)? Judging by the error, you need to define to_json() function for your RoomData. Consult your lib documentation to figure out how to do this, it probably has examples.

Comment: im using in this libary: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/include/nlohmann/json.hpp

@LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: Put such detail in the question please, along with your [MCVE].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using https://github.com/nlohmann/json.

To make this work with one of your types, you only need to provide two functions:

```
using nlohmann::json;

void to_json(json& j, const RoomData& r) {
    j = json{
        {"id", r.id}, 
        {"name", r.name}, 
        {"maxPlayers", r.maxPlayers}, 
        {"timePerQuestion", r.timePerQuestion}, 
        {"isActive", r.isActive}
    };
}

void from_json(const json& j, RoomData& r) {
    r.id = j.at("id").get<int>();
    r.name = j.at("name").get<std::string>();
    r.maxPlayers = j.at("maxPlayers").get<int>();
    r.timePerQuestion = j.at("timePerQuestion").get<int>();
    r.isActive = j.at("timePerQuestion").get<int>();
}
```

Then this will work. Hope this helps up. Cheers.

Comment: @PaulVarghese: What are you talking about? Your answer is only 15 minutes old, and the OP commented 10 minutes ago...

Comment: With this library it's possible to convert from STL containers Check https://github.com/nlohmann/json#conversion-from-stl-containers

Comment: @PaulVarghese But there not example of Vector<class>.. only of simple types like int, double, string..
i want to know how it look if i have in class more types (Vector<class>)

Comment: @OsherAsefa Please find the complete example in this link. Check the last part to see how it works. https://wandbox.org/permlink/mBR5irlVECxzNpOr